# Search column name in csv file using c#

Tags: c#, csv

I need open the csv file and search if in this file I have the column named **fileName**

I have tried on Google but without success.

Can anybody help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you show us what you have tried so far

Comment: [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Are you able to read the csv file into your program?

Comment: consider using this:

var file = File.ReadLines("pathToCsvFile").ToArray();
var columnNames = file[0].Split(',');
foreach (var columnName in columnNames)
{
    if (columnName == "fileName"){
     
    }
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
        public bool CheckFile()
    {
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(File.Open(@"YourFilePath", FileMode.Open));
        string toCheck;
        using (sr)
        {
            toCheck = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }

        return toCheck.Contains("fileName");
    }
```